# String Length in FastReports

Tags: string, delphi

I am extracting data from a Ms-Sql database. But before printing them into my report, i want to check the length of component frMaster."column1" and frMaster."column2". How can i do that? Column1 and Column2 are strings. If my string length is more than 10 characters, my memo's must increase their height, if not, they remain the same. This code has no effect, the memo's remain the same. I have tried to do something like this but it doesn't work on before print event:

```
    if (Length(<frMaster."column1">) > 10)  or (Length(<frMaster."column2">) > 10)                          
   then 
           begin 
                   Memo34.Height:= 0.7;
                   Memo33.Height:= Memo33.Height + 0.35;
                   Memo20.Top := Memo20.Top + 0.35;
                   Memo21.Top := Memo21.Top + 0.35;
                   Memo35.Top := Memo35.Top + 0.35;
                   Memo36.Top := Memo36.Top + 0.35;
                   Memo22.Top := Memo22.Top + 0.35;
                   Memo39.Top := Memo39.Top + 0.35;                           

           end;
```

Comment: -1 "it doesn't work" conveys no useful information. Be precise. Explain carefully and in detail in what way your code fails. Include details of what you expect to see and what you actually see.

Comment: if my string length is more than 10 characters, my memo's must increase their height, if not, they remain the same. this code has no effect, the memo's remain the same

Comment: Please don't add these details in a comment. Click on the edit button and improve the question.

Comment: @user1533838 haven't worked with FR in quite some time, but IIRC there are some nice properties on the components that you add to the report, you might want to check those out, also, there are quite a few events.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the length function that is available in the data tree or as a function to include in your code:

[image: DataTree]

You can make use of it just like in Delphi by overriding an event handler for the memo:

[image]

Ugh!  Oh I see.  You used that and it did not work.  Right!  It seems like I have had that happen before.  I think I probably did something like have the memo just print the text, and then maybe the length of the text, then maybe moving the event to the data band, then maybe making sure the data band has the property Stretched set to True and make sure the memo has the property StretchMode set to smActualHeight or smMaxHeight.

Comment: Thahks, i already founded the solution. I have been set the property StretchedMode  to one of those that you said, but the problem still appearing. I found another way. I just added one more memo having the Visible property set to false, with my desired size. If my strings length are more than 10, the first memo i hide, the other memo i set Visible property to true and assign value to my memo. This thing works much better!!